# What is the correct vertex order of Prim algorithm from this graph?

Tags: graph-algorithm, graph-theory, minimum-spanning-tree, graph-traversal

I want to know the vertex order of the Prim algorithm from this graph:
[image]

My answer is `{a,c,b,e,f,g,d}`, but others said `{a,c,b,e,d,f,g}` or `{a,c,d,e,b,f,g}`.

Which answer is correct?

Answer (score 0):

**Correct!**

The minimum spanning tree, if we choose to **begin from `a`** is as follows:

```
a -> c -> b-> e -> f -> g
     |
     -> d
```

And the order that we add the vertices to the tree is, as you found out, `{a,c,b,e,f,g,d}`.